# TinyMCE stripping spans

Tags: javascript, tinymce

TinyMCE is stripping out spans using the following configuration:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    theme_advanced_resizing_min_width : 550,
    editor_selector : /(tiny_mce|image_mce)/,
    theme : "advanced",
    editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor",
    body_class : "cms",
    content_css : "/css/content.css",
    plugins : "safari, inlinepopups, paste, table",
    file_browser_callback : "tinyBrowser",
    width : 640,
    height : 500,
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold, italic, underline, justifyleft,justifycenter, justifyright, justifyfull , formatselect, |, pasteword ,pastetext, code ",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "undo,redo,|,bullist, numlist,| , outdent,indent, |, link, unlink, image, forecolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "center",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_blockformats : "p,h2,h4",
    convert_urls : false,
    verify_html : true,
    valid_elements : "@[class|style|title],br,h2,h3,h4,-p[align],-strong/b,a[name|href|target]," + 
    "img[src|border=0|alt|width|height|align],hr[width|size|noshade],-em/i,-span" + 
    "table[border|cellspacing|cellpadding|width],tr[rowspan],td[colspan],th[colspan],-ul,-ol,-li" 

});
```

The spans in question are created with the 'forecolor' button and look like this `<span style="color: rgb(0, 255, 0); ">foo</span>`.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: +1 which version of tinymce are you using?

Comment: @Thariama I'm using Version 3.5.4.1 - I updated to the newest version to see if it was a bug in the version that I was using previously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a tinymce fiddle to demostrate the problem - it was there.
I adjusted the valid_elements a bit. It works now. See the tinymce fiddle here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/RNbaab/10

Comment: adding `[data-mce-type]` didn't seem to fix it... although it did set me on the correct path. It seems that some part of TinyMCE wasn't uploaded as I re-uploaded it all and it now works with just `-span`. I added `data-mce-type` to the `@` though as I can't see any reason not include it for all elements which it deems should have it.

Comment: data-mce-type shouldn't be necessesary in never versions of tinymce, the editor uses some invisible spans for bookmarks, those have that attribute